# how to make the tableview cells static and still be accessible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Basically, I have UITableView with a custom cell layout. I have followed the tutorial on AppCoda.com (http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) on how to make them.

Now, I have created a `prepareForSegue` method which opens a collection view when a cell in the UITableView is tapped. Since doing so my UITableView cells are blank and do not have the information I had assigned them with. Furthermore, all the cells in the UITableView show the same data.

How do I create a connection between these two so that it in the perfect state the first picture in the collection will be used as a sample image in the table cell and all the table cells have individual data?

FolderTableViewController.m

```
@implementation FoldersTableViewController
{
    NSArray *folders;

    }
    @synthesize tableView;    

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Folder *folder1 = [Folder new];
    folder1.name = @"Barcelona";
    folder1.date = @"01/12/2014";
    folder1.imageFile = @"city23.gif";

    Folder *folder2 = [Folder new];
    folder2.name = @"Florence";
    folder2.date = @"02/12/2014";
    folder2.imageFile = @"city24.gif";

    Folder *folder3 = [Folder new];
    folder3.name = @"Berlin";
    folder3.date = @"03/12/2014";
    folder3.imageFile = @"city25.gif";

    Folder *folder4 = [Folder new];
    folder4.name = @"Swansea";
    folder4.date = @"04/12/2014";
    folder4.imageFile = @"city26.gif";

    Folder *folder5 = [Folder new];
    folder5.name = @"Cardiff";
    folder5.date = @"05/12/2014";
    folder5.imageFile = @"city29.gif";

    Folder *folder6 = [Folder new];
    folder6.name = @"Pisa";
    folder6.date = @"06/12/2014";
    folder6.imageFile = @"city30.gif";

    Folder *folder7 = [Folder new];
    folder7.name = @"Lisbon";
    folder7.date = @"07/12/2014";
    folder7.imageFile = @"city31.gif";

    Folder *folder8 = [Folder new];
    folder8.name = @"Liverpool";
    folder8.date = @"08/12/2014";
    folder8.imageFile = @"city32.gif";

    Folder *folder9 = [Folder new];
    folder9.name = @"Mannheim";
    folder9.date = @"09/12/2014";
    folder9.imageFile = @"city33.gif";

    folders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:folder1, folder2, folder3, folder4, folder5, folder6, folder7, folder8, folder9, nil];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } else {
        return [folders count];

    }
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [folders count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *foldersIdentifier = @"FolderCell";

    FolderCellTableViewCell *cell = (FolderCellTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:foldersIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FolderCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    Folder *folder = [folders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = folder.name;
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:folder.imageFile];
    cell.datumLabel.text = folder.date;

    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showFolderCollection"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];}
}
```

FolderCollectionViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *photoImages;
```

FolderCollectionViewController.m

```
@synthesize photoImages;

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.photoImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"city23.gif", @"city24.gif", @"city25.gif", @"city26.gif", @"city29.gif", nil];
```

Folder.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageFile;
```

Folder.m:

```
@synthesize name;
@synthesize date;
@synthesize imageFile;
```

My Custom tablecell:

⎮⌈     UI  ⌉ Name           ⎮

⎮⌊Image⌋ Date           ⎮

This is a rough outline of my table cell. I couldn't post an image.

Apologies in advance for any inaccuracies and wrong explanations, I have just started to learn how to program, thus I've got almost no knowledge about it yet.

Comment: Where do you set your dataSource pointer?

Comment: As per your explanation it seems that you want to show first image of collection view in each cell of table view and on clicking that cell you need to show all images in collection view in other view controller. But in your Folder model there is only one image that you are showing in cell where are other images related to that folder.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know whether you meant this:
    interface FoldersTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
    interface FolderCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

Comment: Where do you set `myTableView.dataSource`??

Comment: @AshishP. That's exactly what I meant. So I was wondering where to add the other images as I also have the collection view. Therefore, would I need to assign all the images in the CollectionViewController or within the TableViewController in the folder model? Also would that possibly solve the problem of having a blank table view and all cells having the same data?

Comment: Yes, you can list all images in Folder model you need to show in collectionview. On clicking cell pass that folder model to destination view controller in prepare for segue method. Use that model in view did load for displaying images in collection view.

Comment: @AshishP. Would I add other images to the Folder Model by '@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageFiles;' in my Folder.h and '@synthetize imageFiles;' in Folder.m and then have 'Folder *folder1 = [Folder new];
    folder1.name = @"Barcelona";
    folder1.date = @"01/12/2014";
    folder1.imageFile = @"city23.gif";
    folder1.imageFiles = @"city23.gif", @"city24.gif", @"city25.gif";' ? Also how would I write the prepareForSegue method? Apologies for the numerous questions I have been trying to figure this out for the last two days but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Where do you set `myTableView.dataSource`??

Comment: @HotLicks To be honest I don't think I have set it at all.

Comment: And might that be your problem??

Answer (score 0):

First, I suspect it's because your TableView is not allowing selection.  Hence, `[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` might be returning `nil`.  Check to make sure it is returning what you expect.  If it still is not, delete the segue from the UITableViewCell and create one from FolderTableViewController --> FolderCollectionViewController.  Then, in the UITableViewDelegate implement:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showFolderCollection" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Second, after reading your comments, this is how I would set up your prepare for segue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showFolderCollection"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [sender isKindOfClass:[NSIndexPath class] ? sender : [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Folder *selectedFolder = self.folders[indexPath.row];
        FolderCollectionViewController *fcvc = (FolderCollectionViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [fcvc loadFolder:selectedFolder];
    }
}
```

Note that in `FolderCollectionViewController` the `prepareForSegue` is called after `viewDidLoad` and before `viewWillAppear`

1. FoldersTableViewController: User Touches Row
2. Apple figures out what the tapped Row / Segue should do
3. FolderCollectionViewController: `viewDidLoad`
4. FoldersTableViewController: `prepareForSegue`
5. FolderCollectionViewController: `viewWillAppear:`

So don't rely on `folder` being there in your `viewDidLoad` method for FolderCollectionViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // don't load your data here.
}
```

Instead, create a method like this:

```
-(void) loadFolder:(Folder*)folder {
    self.folder = folder;
    self.photoImages = [folder loadAllImages]; // or whatever
    [self.collectionView reloadData]; // put this here or in -viewWillAppear:
}
```

In regards to the folder class, I'd define it like the following:

```
@interface Folder : NSObject

+(instanceType) folderWithName:(NSString*)name date:(NSDate*)date andImagePaths:(NSArray*)imagePaths;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *imagePaths;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *thumbPath; // use this for the UITableView Image

@end

@implementation Folder

+(instanceType) folderWithName:(NSString*)name date:(NSDate*)date andImagePaths:(NSArray*)imagePaths; {
    Folder *folder = [Folder new];
    folder.name = name;
    folder.date = date;
    folder.imagePaths = imagePaths;
}

- (NSString*) thumbPath {
    if (self.imagePaths != nil &&
        self.imagePaths.count > 0) {
        return [self.imagePaths firstObject];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe it's my way of implementation thats wrong. But thanks anyway!